# ¿ Como apprender red de políticas para un juego de Domineering?

Tags: inteligencia-artificial, redes-neuronales

Quiero aprender una red de políticas para un [juego de Domineering](https://www.jasondavies.com/domineering/#5x5)

- Para cada posición, tengo que recordar la entrada (es decir, el tablero, el tablero volteado,
  y el giro) y la salida del mismo tamaño que el tablero con solo
  el mejor movimiento encontrado por la evaluación Monte Carlo marcado como 1.
- Por ejemplo, líneas de csv para una placa 2x2:

  0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0

A 64*64 example is given [there](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~cazenave/domineering.csv.zip).

que corresponde a tablero, tablero volteado, plano de jugador, moverse para aprender

Tensor de entrada correspondiente:

```
 0 0 1 1 1 1
 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Tensor de salida correspondiente:

```
 1 0
 0 0
```

Quiero aprender una red de políticas con un red neuronal convolucional en python3 o otro. ¿Sabes dónde podría comenzar?

Comment: Hola Marine1, ¿son dos preguntas? Porque en el título pones que querés aprender red de políticas para un juego de Domineering y al final de la pregunta especificas que querés aprender red de políticas con una red neuronal convolucional.
Disculpa la ignorancia, pero si Domineering utiliza una red neuronal convolucional o está basada en ella, ¿el título no debería ser Cómo aprender una red de políticas con un red neuronal convolucional?
Por otra parte, te recomiendo editar la pregunta y agregar la etiqueta python.